# Use map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

How to use map in JavaScript?

```
function get(){
    var map = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};
    if ('key1' in map) {
        return 'hello';
    } else {
        return 'kirti';
    }
}
```

When I'm calling the `get()` function on button click, it can't display any output. What is wrong in above function? Why does it not display any output?

Comment: What output would you expect? There's only returns.

Comment: are you sure it you called your function? because it returns (console.log/alert)

Comment: *"Why does it not display any output?"* Maybe because you are not doing anything with the return value? How are we supposed to know?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understang what the problem is, but I made a jsFiddle to show how to put the value of the return into a div:
jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5v3M5/1/

```
var a = get();
document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: @user3614914 if this did help you kindly accept the answer or upvote because of the effort of the answerer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure really what the expectation is - but if you just want to see if the property exists in the javascript object (map) you can just do this -

```
if(map.key1)
{
  // do what has to be done if the key exists
}
```

or in your case - you can simply use a ternary operator

```
return (map.key1 ? "hello" : "kirti");
```

The '`in`' operator you are using will not work with '`if`' as it is used to loop through all the properties of the object - more about `for..in` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var map = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};
for (var key in map) {
    if(key == 'key1'){
        return 'hello';
    } else {
        return 'kirti';
    }
}
```

Comment: key == 'key1' .. it should be 'key1' == key ... static first so if you forget one = you will get error :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have html like this :

```
Button : <input id="bt" type="button" value="BUTTON">
```

You can use jquery and the `alert()` function to show the result :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bt').on('click', function(){
            alert(get());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get(){
var map = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};
if ('key1' in map) {
   alert('hello');
} else {
    alert('kirti');
}
```

}