# How to add text to end of each array element using map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function that maps over an array and add a string of text to the end of each element in the array. When I do a console.log I just get `undefined`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the array:

```
let arr = ["England","Scotland","Westeros"];
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
dragonMapper = (arr) => {
  let newArr = arr.map(function(e) {
    e += '...here be dragons'
  });
  return newArr;
}

console.log(dragonMapper(newArr));
```

This is what I want the array to be after the function is executed:

```
["England...here be dragons","Scotland...here be dragons","Westeros...here be dragons"];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript add text to beginning of each array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498409/javascript-add-text-to-beginning-of-each-array-element). Voting to close.

Comment: [This will solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578540/use-map-in-javascript) And moreover you have not declared newArr in your code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'s callback function expects a return value

```js
let arr = ["England", "Scotland", "Westeros"];

dragonMapper = arr => {
  let newArr = arr.map(function(e) {
    return e + '...here be dragons'; //Return the concatenated value of 2 strings
  });
  return newArr;
}

console.log(dragonMapper(arr));
```

---

Shorter version, with the arrow function syntax:

```js
let arr = ["England", "Scotland", "Westeros"];

dragonMapper = arr => {
  return arr.map(e => e + '...here be dragons');
}

console.log(dragonMapper(arr));
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you can fix this with code like this:

```js
let arr = ["England","Scotland","Westeros"];
let dragonLands = arr.map(country => country + '...here be dragons');
console.log(dragonLands);
```

But also important is to understand *why* your code fails.  The issue is that Strings are immutable.  So this:

```
   e += '...here be dragons'
```

does not change the value of `e` in your original array but instead returns a new String, which is immediately thrown away, since you don't assign it to something or return it.

It can be confusing because this looks fairly similar:

```js
let arr = [
    {name: "England", id: 1}, 
    {name: "Scotland", id: 2}, 
    {name: "Westeros", id: 3}
];
arr.forEach(country => country.name += '...here be dragons');
console.log(arr);
```

But there are important differences.  First, `map` returns the result of applying the function to the elements.  `forEach`, in contrast, is only important for side effects, in this case mutating the elements supplied to it.

Second, `country => country.name += '...here there be dragons'` does two things.  It creates a new String as did your version, but then it assigns it back to `country.name`.  Objects are *not* immutable.

`map` is an extremely useful construct, but when using it, it's essential to understand that it's the *result* of the function it invokes that's important.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
let arr = ["England","Scotland","Westeros"];
let result = arr.map(country => `${country}...here be dragons`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `e += '...here be dragons'` you can simply do `e + '...here be dragons'` and return the new value.

Also, you are calling `dragonMapper` with  `newArr` but it needs to be called with `arr`

```js
let arr = ["England", "Scotland", "Westeros"];

dragonMapper = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    return e + '...here be dragons'
  });

}

console.log(dragonMapper(arr));
```